# Whats an alternative to having to use sqlite prepared statements to escape characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm working on an iPhone app, which uses the SQLite database, and I'm trying to handle escape characters. I know that there is LIKE ESCAPE to handle escape characters in select statements, but in my application i have SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE actions and i really don't know how to go about handling escape characters.

Comment: Did either of these answers work out for you? Please accept one by clicking on the gray checkmark next to the answer if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), and then you won't have to.  It has [built-in parameter binding support](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), and that will take care of any escaping you need for you.

Comment: Specifically, you should say, use FMDB's parameter binding feature.

Comment: @phooze yes, that is what I mean. :)

Comment: im using sqlite along with sqlcipher soo FMDB is out of the question thanks for the suggestion though, will use it the next time im developing an app.

Comment: seelani, FMDB is a wrapper AROUND sqlite that handles things like this for you.

Comment: oh, :| my bad, i thought it stood for FM-database or something.silly me.i will take a look at it then!

Comment: should i really be using FMDB? it is outdated and also lacks proper documentation. what about core data, is there anyway to handle them escape characters?

Comment: @seelani The thing with FMDB is that it's a thin layer on top of sqlite. IOW, it's a more object-oriented way of interacting with a database than using the c API directly. Since you're using sqlcipher, it seems you want db encryption, which coredata would not give you. FMDB can handle sqlcipher, and it will take care of all the parameter binding (and thus escaping) for you. Whenever I need to access a sqlite db, I never use anything else.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using sqlite3_exec() all-in-one function,
you dont need to use sqlite3_bind* functions..
just pass the string to **sqlite3_mprintf()** with **%q** token

```
sqlite3_mprintf("%q","it's example");
```

and the output string is

```
it''s example
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply have to tell SQLite what your escape character is at the end of the SQL statement. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RevenueChange LIKE '%0\%' ESCAPE '\'
```

The LIKE will match values such as `30%`, `140%`, etc. The character I used, `\`, could be anything.

Comment: does this include INSERT and UPDATE statements as well?

Comment: Yes, it does, it can be used everywhere.